# MPI- combining information

Tags: c++, mpi

Is there any good way to combine information about messages in a single send? 
For example I want to combine a grid number and number of a handler(each is a separate instance) on this grid. I can do smth like this in tag: gridnum*N + handlernum*M or any combination, but this limits the number of both

So, on one side i want to call

```
MPI_ISend(info,.., dest, ..some_tag, ..)
```

On the other side, I want to receive by the tag (perhaps i is also an info i wan to send): 
`MPI_Recv (&val[i], .. , source_any, tag, ..).` How can I achieve this, I don't quite understand how to safely check info struct params, if I send at first

```
struct info { int gridnum; int hadlernum;}
```

Comment: its some time ago since I used mpi, but iirc you can send any messages you want, eg a `struct { int gridnum; int handlernum;};`

Comment: @tobi303 The type should be trivially copyable (like the example struct you show), but other than that, that's correct.

Comment: @tobi303, I know, but then I should receive every incoming message and check if it is a right grid and handler. And tags check it before receiving

Comment: @BaummitAugen, I want to send a value from one process, but receive it on a specific handler and grid in another one. I don't see, how this struct can help, I cannot put it in tag

Comment: @tobi303, and can I then safely check the structure, if I receive it? The other process may also come and override the checking variables

Comment: Please clarify more specifically what you intend to do, by editing the question. Providing a source code example would really help. As is, it is unclear what you really want to achieve.